# Assembly Interpretation - Register confusion

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I'm working on an assignment for class where I have to interpret assembly. I know the input to defuse the bomb is 442, but I'm not exactly sure why.

```
8048c80:    83 ec 2c                sub    $0x2c,%esp
8048c83:    c7 44 24 1c 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,0x1c(%esp)
8048c8a:    00 
8048c8b:    8d 44 24 1c             lea    0x1c(%esp),%eax
8048c8f:    89 44 24 08             mov    %eax,0x8(%esp)
8048c93:    c7 44 24 04 64 a7 04    movl   $0x804a764,0x4(%esp)
8048c9a:    08 
8048c9b:    8b 44 24 30             mov    0x30(%esp),%eax
8048c9f:    89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
8048ca2:    e8 59 fc ff ff          call   8048900 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
8048ca7:    83 f8 01                cmp    $0x1,%eax
8048caa:    74 05                   je     8048cb1 <phase_1+0x31>
8048cac:    e8 e4 07 00 00          call   8049495 <explode_bomb>
8048cb1:    81 7c 24 1c ba 01 00    cmpl   $0x1ba,0x1c(%esp)
8048cb8:    00 
8048cb9:    74 05                   je     8048cc0 <phase_1+0x40>
8048cbb:    e8 d5 07 00 00          call   8049495 <explode_bomb>
8048cc0:    83 c4 2c                add    $0x2c,%esp
8048cc3:    c3                      ret
```

Sscanf takes two values, "%d" and my inputted value, but I'm not sure where it stores the value or why %eax is 1 or why 0x1c(%esp) has the value. We store 0x0 there at the beginning, and then move 0x30(%esp), %eax, so shouldn't it be 0? Any help understanding this would be very much appreciated.

To be clear, this is x86 in at&t syntax.

Comment: Do you at least know C? Do you understand how `sscanf(input, "%d", &var)` places the parsed input into `var`, overwriting any previous value? Do you understand that `sscanf` returns the number of items converted, hence it will be `1` for success?

Comment: Your C or assembly textbook will include information on this using words like 'stack' and 'return value'. 

`0x1c(%ESP)` is calculating displacement from the stack pointer, which as you identified is where the actual value is being stored. 

`EAX` holds the return value.

Comment: The first 8 lines are boilerplate stuff. Line 9 checks that scanf returns 1, if not the bomb explodes. Line 12 checks the value read in by scanf, if it's not ox1ba the bomb explodes.

Comment: May I suggest running your code in gdb one instruction at a time while looking at the contents of registers?